# Multi-dimensional array notation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays `A` and `i` with dimensions `(1, 3, 3)` and `(1, 2, 2)` respectively. I want to define a new array `I` which gives the elements of `A` based on `i`. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
i=np.array([[[0,0],[1,2],[2,2]]])
A = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]], dtype=float)
I=A[0,i]
print([I])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[[[1.000000000, 2.000000000, 3.000000000],
         [1.000000000, 2.000000000, 3.000000000]],

        [[4.000000000, 5.000000000, 6.000000000],
         [7.000000000, 8.000000000, 9.000000000]],

        [[7.000000000, 8.000000000, 9.000000000],
         [7.000000000, 8.000000000, 9.000000000]]]])]
```

The desired output is

```
[array(([[[1],[6],[9]]]))
```

Comment: can you elaborate this, ```I want to define a new array I which gives the elements of A based on i.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [131]: A.shape, i.shape
Out[131]: ((1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 2))
```

That leading size 1 dimension just adds a `[]` layer, and complicates indexing (a bit):

```
In [132]: A[0]
Out[132]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

This is the indexing that I think you want:

```
In [133]: A[0,i[0,:,0],i[0,:,1]]
Out[133]: array([1, 6, 9])
```

If you really need a trailing size 1 dimension, add it after:

```
In [134]: A[0,i[0,:,0],i[0,:,1]][:,None]
Out[134]: 
array([[1],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

From the desired numbers, I deduced that you wanted to use the 2 columns of `i` as indices to two different dimensions of `A`:

```
In [135]: i[0]
Out[135]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

Another way to do the same thing:

```
In [139]: tuple(i.T)
Out[139]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]),
 array([[0],
        [2],
        [2]]))

In [140]: A[0][tuple(i.T)]
Out[140]: 
array([[1],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enter

```
I=A[0,:1,i[:,1]]
```

Comment: But the output of that is `array([[[2.], [3.]]])`, and not the target `array([[[1], [6], [9]]])`

Comment: The question has been edited. This is what was intended before editing the output. That is, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy's `take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) for that.
However, `take` works with a flat index, so you will need to use `[0, 5, 8]` for your indexes instead.

Here is an example:

```
>>> I = [A.shape[2] * x + y for x,y in i[0]] # Convert to flat indexes
>>> I = np.expand_dims(I, axis=(1,2))
>>> A.take(I)
array([[[1.]],
       [[6.]],
       [[9.]]])
```